# How do I correctly mock a debounce event when unit testing UI in jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, debouncing

I currently have a unit test that will mock the click of a button. I've recently added a debounce function around it:

```js
import * as lodash from 'lodash';

//...bunch of code in between

const buttonChangerTrue= lodash.debounce(() => buttonChanger(true, row), 500);
```

This click of the button will cause a change in the UI which will basically change the icon color (assuming the end user doesn't rapidly click it).

For the sake of brevity, I've removed the excess code for the test

```js
this.when.push({

            beforeEachRender: () => {

                count++;
                jest.useFakeTimers();
                if (count === 1) {
                    this.mockHttpRequests();
                } else {
                    this.mockHttpRequestsReversed('buttonPressed');
                }

            },

            describe: 'When an unsaved search is ran and an agent is pinned',

            then: async () => {
                test('Then a note should be created', async () => {


                    const button = tableBody.children[1].children[1].children[0].children[0];
                    const stickyNoteBeforePinning =
                        this.getById(document.body, 'notes-69fc105ad2c94edf16efb1f4de125c38093aefe9') as HTMLElement;

                    if (!button ) {
                        throw 'button  not found';
                    }

                    await wait(() => {
                        fireEvent.click(button);
                    });

                    jest.runTimersToTime(1000);

                    const stickyNoteAfterPinning =
                        this.getById(document.body, 'notes-ec9c2a3041a18a4a7d8d8b4943292cb8aa92a2f5') as HTMLElement;

                    expect(stickyNoteBeforePinning).toHaveAttribute('class', 'lead material-icons text-light');
                    expect(stickyNoteBeforePinning).not.toBe(stickyNoteAfterPinning);
                    expect(stickyNoteAfterPinning).toHaveAttribute('class', 'lead material-icons text-pink'); // Fails here
                });

            },
        });
```

Please let me know if you need more information but this click of a button does make an API call, I've mocked the call in the test as well. When I remove the debounce function and run it as normal -- it passes the test just fine. I've tried a number of things like `jest.useFakeTimers();` in the `beforeEachRender` portion and calling `jest.runTimersToTime(1000);` right after it. I've also tried using `jest.advanceTimersByTime(500);` right after the click too. Nothing seems to be working.

Edit: I ended up removing the tests for now. I read that Jest does have a version that can take into account something like `jest.useFakeTimers('modern');` and that will simulate the debouncing. Will report back if I can get results on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useFakeTimers()` from `sinon`

Here its an example of use:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

let clock;

beforeEach(() => {
  clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

afterEach(() => {
  clock.restore();
});

test('debounce', () => {
  // wait 1000ms
  clock.tick(1000);
  func() // Execute your function.
  expect(func).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // func called
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I installed the dependency, placed `clock.tick(1000);` right above the `await wait` function in the test but it errors out with `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 100000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.`

Comment: Maybe try switching the order of the function call and the call to tick() and see if that fixes it?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha Sorry for the late response. I tried that as well and to no avail. I ended up just removing the tests and will re-visit on refactoring it. There might be a version of Jest that can account for debouncing but its in alpha stage